# rsyslog server on windows

Tags: windows, rsyslog

Is rsyslog server available on Windows?

Comment: I believe the folks on serverfault know better

Comment: http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Platforms

Comment: I was hoping there may be some utilities on Windows which function as a rsyslog server.

Answer (score 3):

They have winsyslog. If you want an open-source solution, take a look at [nxlog](http://nxlog.org).